# Maximizing the parameter panel in the ReportViewer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a WinForms application that uses the ReportViewer control. I have a report with 22 parameters. When the page with the ReportViewer control loads, the bottom four parameters (two rows of two parameters) are cut off, and users have to manually expand the parameter panel to see them. Is there a parameter I can set or method I can call to automatically resize the area above the toolbar?

Comment: Woa, *22* parameters? You're sure that this is not an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/162730)?

Comment: I would like to see more ability to customise the parameter bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry no. This bar is automatically populated however it can be displayed and hidden.

Comment: I have to agree with @glh. All the research and attempts to change the parameter bar haven't worked.